# FO .net embed images (gif)

Tags: .net, image, pdf, gif

I am currently using [FO.net](http://fonet.codeplex.com/) for generating my PDF report coming out of a .net 3.5 application.  I need to embed a GIF image into the PDF. I do not want to have a file reference, but actually have the content of the image as part of the PDF.

I have previously done this using SVG using the Ecrion FO Engine, however the free FO.Net (which is a C# port of Java's fo) does not currently support SVG files.

The codeplex page specifies that it can, although I don't think this is confirmed and there is no information I could find on how to do this.

Any help in this dilemma would be much appreciated :)

As a side-note I am well aware you get what you pay for. However embedding images into a PDF is a pretty important part of any PDF report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually converted the gif images to jpg using gimp to get around this.

Comment: how would you use a filepath reference to the image? I cant seem to get my app to pick up the correct file path...

Comment: You reference the image relative to the XSL-FO file. Hope that helps. :)